# Dynamic horizontal rule with centered text react native

Tags: react-native

I would like to have the grow horizontally not vertically. My current code is this

```
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ width: 50, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white' }}>Here is the problem</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
            </View>
```

but this grows vertically any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limiting the `width` of the `Text` component, thus the text will not have enough space. Therefore, it will be breaking into several lines.

If we remove the fixed `width`, it will use the available vertical space.

```js
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
                <View>
                    <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: 'white' }}>Here is the problem</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }} />
            </View>
```

Before change

[image]

After change

[image]